# jqgrid & Lib.Web.Mvc.JQuery.JqGrid.DataAnnotations:how hide column?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, data-annotations, lib.web.mvc

I have this jqgrid

```
var grid = new JqGridHelper<VisualisationModel>(
    "gridVisualizzazioni",
    caption: null,
    dataType: JqGridDataTypes.Json,      
    methodType: JqGridMethodTypes.Post,
    pager:true,
    sortingName: "IndicatoreVisualizzazioniPk",
    sortingOrder: JqGridSortingOrders.Asc,
    url: Url.Action("LoadGrid", new {
                                      indicatorePk = Model.IndicatorePk
                                    }),
    autoWidth: true,
    viewRecords: true, 
    loadComplete:"SetCellBackColor");
```

And in my model I create some column...

In particular

```
[Required]
[JqGridColumnFormatter(JqGridColumnPredefinedFormatters.Integer)]
public int AggregazioniDatiId { get; set; }
```

It is possible hide the above column in jqGrid by DataAnnotation?

I have tried with

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
```

but in the colModel the column don't appear and then my jquery code does not work

```
var grid = $("#gridVisualizzazioni");
var selRowId = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
var celValue = grid.jqGrid ('getCell', selRowId, 'AggregazioniDatiId');
```

Thanks in advance.

Sara

Comment: [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)] did u try this? same error?

Comment: or in this http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnetmvc.aspx, in the model where they are using editable:false for columns, you can use hidden:true also. I dont know how u r constructing your grid.

Comment: @PiyushSardana Thanks. [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)] works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
```